# How can I align the navigation bar to the right

Tags: html, css, alignment, navbar

I have tried changing float to right, and changing position and aligning but nothing works. Please help. I can't seem to get it to work no matter what I try. I have tried use other codes that have the navbar to the right but that doesn't work either. Hope that anyone can help me with this problem:)

```
  <div class="Navigasjon">
            <a class="active1" href="Index.php">Forside</a>
            <a href="Rappernavn.php">Rappere</a>
            <a href="Album.php">Album</a>

        </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.Navigasjon {
position: absolute;
margin: 14px;
width: 100%;
top: 0px;
background-color: transparent;
overflow: hidden;
}

.Navigasjon a {
float: left;
display: block;
color: Black;
text-align: right;
padding: 18px 22px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 550;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.Navigasjon a:hover {
background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
color: black;
}

.active1 {
background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimized code:

HTML

```
<div class="Navigasjon">
  <a class="active1" href="Index.php">Forside</a>
  <a href="Rappernavn.php">Rappere</a>
  <a href="Album.php">Album</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.Navigasjon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 14px;
}

.Navigasjon a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 18px 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 550;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.Navigasjon a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
}

.active1 {
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for optimising the code, and helping me align it right!

Answer (score 1):

You were applying `float:left` to `.Navigasjon a`.

```css
.Navigasjon {
  margin: 14px;
  width: calc(100% - 28px);
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}

.Navigasjon a {
  display: block;
  color: Black;
  padding: 18px 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 550;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

.Navigasjon a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
}

.active1 {
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="Navigasjon">
  <a class="active1" href="Index.php">Forside</a>
  <a href="Rappernavn.php">Rappere</a>
  <a href="Album.php">Album</a>

</div>
```

Comment: @artin0905 If my answer solves your question, please consider accepting!